# DC voltage amplifier circuit with up to 10kV output, up to 1mA

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, dc-dc-converter, battery-operated

What components would I need for a circuit that would be able to magnify an input voltage in the 10s of volts at an appropriate wattage to produce an output voltage of up to 10kV at 1mA? I've read about high gain operational amplifiers,  transistors and components simply called voltage amplifiers, but they seem to deal with comparatively microscopic input voltages.

My intentions are to supply the input via a battery, directed by a microcontroller to operate a soft robotic actuator.

Edit to provide more context:

I want to drive a HASEL soft robotic actuator. The gist can be found here https://imechanica.org/node/22096. As mentioned by one of the authors, "There are a few companies (EMCO and Pico Electronics) which specialize in miniature DC-DC high voltage amplifiers which can be powered by a cell phone battery and output 10kV". I would like to learn more about these components - specifically what they consist of and how I might either build or go about sourcing the right thing.

I apologise for any ignorance, as I have very little knowledge of electronics. I would appreciate any open-ended answers.

A further edit: I appreciate the safety concerns people have raised, and understand that this is beyond my reach as a hobbyist at this stage. My curiosity remains however, and I intend to visit this project post safety training and adequate experience.

Comment: Probably something like a stack of IGBTs with isolated drivers. Aside perhaps from some vacuum tubes there are not many individual control elements that can linearly control 10kV. Some IGBTs can control a few kV. *Not* a beginner project.

Comment: What sort of bandwidth are you looking at? A lot of high-voltage power supplies have an analog control input, though the bandwidth on it is usually pretty low.

Comment: I think @SpehroPefhany says it. This isn't a project for someone who has "very little knowledge of electronics."

Comment: If the signal is AC maybe transformer would be a solution.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I've updated the question to give more context. @Hearth I'm not sure whether bandwidth is applicable, as my power supply would be outputting DC

Comment: @TVKid You call it an "amplifier"; that implies you want to amplify some signal that could vary. Bandwidth is definitely applicable.

Comment: @Hearth Ah, I see where you're coming from. For my application I would need it to be on the order of around 10-30Hz

Answer (score 2):

10kV at 1mA - that's basically a large color TV anode supply. You'd want to close a control loop around it to regulate the flyback oscillator to give you the voltage you want. Presumably those actuators aren't very fast? We'd like to see a link to those actuators BTW.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've amended the OP to give details about the actuator. I'm unsure of what you would consider "slow", but these actuators are able to be driven at frequencies in the dozens of Hz

Comment: @TVKid That’s a tough problem you got then. If you can’t find anything off the shelf, it’ll be a bit of design work to make one. You’ll still need a 10kV DC supply and there are modules that do that. Then you’ll want a linear stage after that, carefully set up with multiple pass elements dealing with a slice of the drop out voltage each. A partial D-class drive scheme may work, but it’s tough at such high voltages. The capacitive losses will eat any power savings. A class A driver is your best bet I think.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: A stack of Cockcroft-Walton voltage multipliers on the secondary side of a transformer, with primary excited by a suitable oscillator.  However, this project is not suitable for someone with "very little knowledge of electronics".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how rapidly you need to change the voltage level, you could step up AC using a transformer and then rectify to DC.  You could possibly use an audio amplifier to generate a signal of up to tens of volts and then step up with a ratio of 50:1 or so.  With a class D amplifier you could have reasonably high efficiency.  As others have said though, anything in the kilovolt range needs to be approached with the greatest care.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As a minimum, I'd want to be able to perform about 5 10kV pulses per second (from a constant input voltage on the order of 10V), and certainly no more than 35 pulses per second

Comment: @TVKid thanks for adding the link to the actuators.  Thinking along the lines of an audio amplifier, you could reasonably generate a 10kHz (at least) sine wave and step that up using a reasonably small transformer as the frequency is significantly higher than AC mains.  Depending on the characteristics of the load it may be enough just to switch off the input signal at the end of the pulse rather than actively clamp the output voltage.  In general you’d want to do as much as possible on the low-voltage side and have only the bare minimum handling the high voltage…

Comment: As the latter will be exotic, expensive and hazardous.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little Googling on EMCO (now called Xp Power) and found [this](https://www.xppower.com/product/F-Series) which seems to suit your use case pretty well.

The F101R in particular delivers 10kV at 1mA (10W) so it seems to be exactly what you're after. You should always take care when working with high voltage but at this wattage the worst you'd be in for is a nasty zap so long as it's only hooked up to a small battery.

If you're interested in how it works under-the-hood, there's quite a bit of information in the [datasheet](https://www.xppower.com/portals/0/pdfs/SF_F_Series.pdf)